# How to make real page cache in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, wordpress-theming

I want to make page cache of static pages in my WordPress theme (and basically I know how to implement it)

The problem is that when making theme - the first time when I "get any control" about what is happening is inside **functions.php** file of theme, and this file is loaded about 1 sec after request starts (before it is loading all wordpress functions stuff, I quess some sql - **but I dont need that all as I'm using page cache**, just want to render saved html - btw. thats what is cache about for me).

So the question is - **Am I able to - from level of theme - take control of WordPress initialization before theme functions.php?** - the best would be as soon as possible after request start

**Why?** Getting html from cache takes 0,05s in my case, and time from request start to functions.php is 1s so in sume it gives 1,05s that I could reduce to like 0,1s if I'm able to 'capture' request earlier.

I dont want to modify non-theme files like WordPress core files as many people will use this theme, but if there is no other way than maybe but I dont feel it would be good practice?

Comment: I think you don't need to recreate the wheel? https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Comment: I know this plugin - but the same issue is here I guess (am I wrong?) - it loads some basic stuff, make some sql queries, creates global variables and then AFTER all this (that is completly not needed in case of page output caching) it starts loading some 'cache plugin'. If you could load w3-total-cache just on the first line of request if you dont need wordpress functionalities at all it would be even faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess this might help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init

this hook gets executed when wordpress has loaded but before anything is saved

Answer (score 0):

Create a drop-in plugin called `advanced-cache.php`, put it in `wp-content` (*not `wp-content/plugins`*), put `define('WP_CACHE', true);` in `wp-config.php`, and get to work.

Make sure not to cache:

- admin pages
- 404 pages
- POSTed pages
- pages with query strings
- pages that will be redirected
- etc